# SLURM: Changing the maximum number of simultaneously running tasks for a running array job

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I have set of an array job as follows:

```
sbatch --array=1:100%5 ...
```

which will limit the number of simultaneously running tasks to 5. The job is now running, and I would like to change this number to 10 (i.e. I wish I'd run `sbatch --array=1:100%10 ...`).

The [documentation on array jobs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) mentions that you can use `scontrol` to change options after the job has started. Unfortunately, it's not clear what this option's variable name is, and I don't think it is listed in the documentation of the sbatch command [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OUTPUT-ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES).

Any pointers well received.

Comment: Modifying a job is done with the `scontrol` command so it is in the `scontrol` man page that you would find the option's name https://slurm.schedmd.com/scontrol.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can change the array throttling limit with the following command:

```
scontrol update ArrayTaskThrottle=<count> JobId=<jobID>
```